# Search Widget in action bar not displaying the default text

Tags: android

Hi the search widget in the action bar of my application is not displaying the default text for some reason. I am sure I might be missing something.
The code looks like below:-

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    try{
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.v(TAG,"inflated"+e.getMessage()+"--"+e.getClass()+"-"+e.getClass());
        }
    return true;
}
```

menu/activity_main

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
 </menu>
```

values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="search_title">Search Data</string>
</resources>
```

The search widget is working perfectly , the only thing is the default text "Search Data" is not showing..
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use this

```
searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_title));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. By the way what is android:title supposed to do then